# Why does json4s need a Scala compiler as a runtime dependency

Tags: scala, json4s

I've discovered that by using json4s native

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
        <artifactId>json4s-native_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

brings scalap and scala-compiler dependencies.

Why does it need it?

Does it generate code on the fly at runtime?

Why doesn't it use macros that do this processing at compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The people of json4s have answered me in [this issue](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/108#issuecomment-47322340) the following:

Because we need to read the byte code to find out information about scala primitives. This is more necessary on 2.9 than it is on 2.10